# Change eclipse plugin project icon

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image: eclipse plugin project]

How can i change icon of eclipse plugin project by java code. See in image i want to change Std_lib default icon. I would be so helpful for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want to have a look @ the [external link](https://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-5-adding-icons-and-a-new-project-structure/) for Eclipse Plug-in development.

Comment: Change the icon of a file folder to what?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc i need to change icon of folder